# In Cordova, how do I render a website instead of an index.html?

Tags: android, cordova

I already have a webapp that I want to cordova to render.  How do I do that?  My confusion is the `cordova create` creates an "index.html" which doesn't seem appropriate in my context: That file would be hosted on the server.  Is there a way to tell cordova to show a URL instead of html file?

I think I *could* just use an iframe to the website in the "index.html", but I'm assuming there's a more straight forward way.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `cordova/config.xml` to put a url in there instead of a file like so:

```
 <content src="http://www.yoursite.com" />
```

Comment: First of all, to load an external web page you don't need cordova at all, just use a regular android webview. Second, don't do that, apps that just are website wrappers got bad reviews

Comment: @jcesarmobile You're saying I should learn the Android API enough to create my own webview?  Then do the same for iOS, then the windows mobile api... Tomorrow when I need to use a feature of the device (eg: camera, gps) I'll have to build my own version of Cordova.  I don't think you're suggesting a good path to go down.  If you disagree, please explain in more detail.

Comment: You don't have to create your own webview, in most cases just drag it to the screen and a few lines of code to load the url you want. Cordova webview have a purpose, it's purpose is to call native APIs from javascript, if you load external pages you can't use the APIs, so there is no point on using cordova at all. You can use cordova to save 10-30 minutes of reading how to use a webview for each platform, but loading external websites won't allow you to use the cordova API when you need it

Comment: @jcesarmobile ah I didn't know that.  I haven't research/tried to use Cordova plugins yet.  I assumed that external websites could use them.